# PHP and/or is showing opposite of what it should be

Tags: php, while-loop, operators

I'm showing database results, and I would like to hide empty rows. I am checking to make sure both columns do not equal 0 before displaying. I thought that would need an `&&` operator, but that is not displaying the row if just one column has a 0. If I change it to `||`, the data displays correctly. Is there a reason why this is working in the opposite way as expected?

Here's the php loop that is currently working correctly (but not as expected):

```
while($placement = mysqli_fetch_assoc($placeQuery)){
    echo '<tr>';
    if(($totals[$placeID][$totaldate]['impr'] != 0) || ($totals[$placeID][$totaldate]['amt'] != 0)){
        echo '<td>'.$placement['type_name'].'</td>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean why it is not working with a AND operator?

Comment: you want `(x == '') && (y == '') { empty row found }`, basically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the "not working as expected" part of the question, it might help to read up on logical functions.  Learn truth tables and this kind of thing gets a lot more clear.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table

AND will be false for:
0,0
1,0
0,1
and will give true for 1,1, so using AND means you display only if both columns are not zero.

OR will be false only for:
0,0
and true for the other combinations, so using OR will display UNLESS both are 0.